# ODE fitting with Symfit - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes

Tags: python, curve-fitting, differential-equations, symfit

I'm trying to solve and fit these coupled [Differential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaq3f.png) with Symfit. I've tried following the documentation for [ODE fitting](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#ode-fitting), looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202708/13186278) to a similar question and searched [the error in other contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes), but without any luck. My code is supposed be used on experimental data, but as a start I've just created somewhat similar data. The relevant code is:

```py
#Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from symfit import variables, parameters, Parameter, Fit, D, ODEModel, cos, sin, atan, asin, sqrt

#Constants
m  = 0.01      #Unit: kg    - Mass of object
mt = 0.5 * m   #Unit: kg    - Related to moment of inertia (\tilde{m] in the equations)
R  = 0.1       #Unit: m     - Radius of object
g  = 9.82      #Unit: m/s^2 - gravitational acceleration 
#Variables and parameters
x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, t = variables("x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, t")  #x-position, y-position, x-velocity, y-velocity, time
p         = Parameter("p", min=1, max=4)
c, d      = parameters("c,d")       #d is \gamma in the equations

#Generate proxy data
t_vals  = np.linspace(0,10,100)            #Choosen time interval
x1_data = 8*np.sin(0.15*t_vals)+7*t_vals   #x-data proxy
x2_data = 10*np.sin(0.15* t_vals)-2*t_vals #y-data proxy
x3_data = 0.15*8*np.cos(0.15*t_vals)-7     #vx-data proxy
x4_data = 0.15*10*np.cos(t_vals)-2         #vy-data proxy

#Model
model_dict = {
    D(x_1, t) : x_3,
    D(x_2, t) : x_4,
    D(x_3, t) : -d/mt * (x_3**2 + x_4**2)**((p-1)/2) * x_3 + c*(x_3**2+x_4**2)/(mt*R) * cos(atan(x_1/x_2) + asin(R/sqrt(x_1**2+x_2**2))),
    D(x_4, t) : -d/mt * (x_3**2 + x_4**2)**((p-1)/2) * x_4 + c*(x_3**2+x_4**2)/(mt*R) * sin(atan(x_1/x_2) + asin(R/sqrt(x_1**2+x_2**2)))+m/mt * g,
}

ode_model  = ODEModel(model_dict, initial={t: 0.0, x_1: 0, x_2: 3, x_3: 0, x_4: 1})

fit        = Fit(ode_model, t=tdata, x_1=x1_data, x_2=x2_data, x_3=x3_data, x_4=x4_data)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ef065dc7aeb9> in <module>
     27 
     28 fit        = Fit(ode_model, t=tdata, x_1=x1_data, x_2=x2_data, x_3=x3_data, x_4=x4_data)
---> 29 fit_result = fit.execute()
     30 
     31 t_vec      = np.linspace(0,10,1000)

[...]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (5,) and requested shape (100,)
```

I'm rather inexperienced in using Symfit, but I suppose the two arrays the error is referring to, is the five variables and the 100 datapoints each of them have. I have no idea what causes this error, except maybe a lack of initial guesses and badly generated data. *The problem simply was that I used the wrong time array*

EDIT: As user mikuszefski pointed out, I had used `tdata` where `t_vals` should've been used. **This solved my initial error**. The same user also correctly predicted numerical troubles, as some fitted values are of magnitude 10^300. I will edit my post once I find a solution.
I have also written my imports and defined `g`.

Comment: Hi, why is it `tdata` and not `t_val` what is `g`? Try to make a running example that reproduces the error. That should include all imports etc. Try not to make an `from symfit import *`.

Comment: Also note that there is numerically some trouble ahead. You potentially have division by zero (including the case of `p<1`) and the argument of the `asin` might become greater than 1

Comment: Of course it has to be `t_val`, `tdata` has nothing to do with this part of the code, and the error is no more. Now, as you correctly predicted, the problem is numerical troubles. When I plot the data, a few point is of order 10^300. I will try to exclude these and see how the fit goes. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: This might be more fit of a seperate, new question, but do you have any idea as to how I can get the fit function to ignore values that tend to infinity? I defined a function that removed outliers AFTER the fit, but that of course does not change the fit and I still get terrible fits (9/10 cases just y=0)

Comment: First thing I'd do is rewrite the diff Eq. You have terms of type `sin(a +b)` and `cos( a+b)`, which you can expand, e.g. `sin(a + b) = sin a cos b + cos a sin b`. As `a = arctan u` and `b = arcsin v` So if I did not a mistake in my quick calc that gives `( u/ sqrt( 1+u^2 ) ) * sqrt( 1 - v^2 ) + ( 1 /  sqrt( 1 + u^2 ) ) * v ` ...similar for the `cos`-case. So you already eliminate the unfortunate (inverse) trigonometric functions....--> much better...by far more stable.